# Anylogic: How to enable/disable path between nodes using a control

Tags: path, anylogic

Refer to image.
The objective is to "enable/disable" the yellow path between experiment runs (purpose is to measure time savings if vehicles have the ability to use short-cut).

What is the easiest way to do this programmatically (i.e. not adding/removing the path manually).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Material-handling transporters using the network, you can programmatically call one of these functions to prohibit usage:
[image]

If not, you will have to [create the network programmatically](https://anylogic.help/markup/create-network-by-code.html#creating-network) upfront and either include/exclude the path accordingly.

One trick before going there: You can try to `path.setBidirectional(false);` to prohibt travelling against the drawn direction. But obviously, this only helps in some cases.

PS: You can also go all out and take full control of your network by agent-ifying it, see my full workshop here: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2022/8/6/taking-control-of-your-network-agent-based-pathfinding

Comment: Ben, thanks for your well illustrated explanation and the options.